# How do I install a package I find on rosindex.github.io?

Tags: python, linux, ros

One of my packages is missing a python module called `controller_manager_msgs`

The package containing the source appears to be found here:
http://rosindex.github.io/p/controller_manager_msgs/

How do I install such a package to my ROS Kinetic distribution?

Other related links:
http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager
http://rosindex.github.io/p/controller_manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller_manager_msgs` is part of the `ros_control` package, you can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kenetic-ros-control ros-kenetic-ros-controllers
```

Alternatively, you can download the package into your catkin workspace (e.g., `catkin_ws`) and build it yourself:

```
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control.git ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there another way with `rosdep install`?